# Cannot access protected member 'object.MemberwiseClone()'

Tags: c#, clone

I'm trying to use `.MemberwiseClone()` on a custom class of mine, but it throws up this error:

```
Cannot access protected member 'object.MemberwiseClone()' via a qualifier of type 'BLBGameBase_V2.Enemy'; the qualifier must be of type 'BLBGameBase_V2.GameBase' (or derived from it)
```

What does this mean? Or better yet, how can I clone an `Enemy` class?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Within any class `X`, you can only call `MemberwiseClone` (or any other protected method) on an instance of `X`.  (Or a class derived from `X`)

Since the `Enemy` class that you're trying to clone doesn't inherit the `GameBase` class that you're trying to clone it in, you're getting this error.

To fix this, add a public `Clone` method to `Enemy`, like this:

```
class Enemy : ICloneable {
    //...
    public Enemy Clone() { return (Enemy)this.MemberwiseClone(); }
    object ICloneable.Clone() { return Clone(); }
}
```

Comment: But I thought MemberwiseClone was a method of Object, which afaik all classes are dervied from?

Comment: Yes, but you can't call a different class's protected method unless it inherits from _you_.  Otherwise, you'd be able to call any protected member (including `MemberwiseClone`) on any class simply by inheriting from that class.  This would make `protected` almost useless.

Comment: "protected" is another way of saying: only the class itself knows when MemberwiseClone() is the proper thing to do.  It rarely is, google "deep copy".

Comment: `ICloneable` not available in Silverlight 5.0

Comment: @PeterLee: You don't need to use `ICloneable`.

Comment: @SLaks, I see. but it seems we have to create a new class to inherit a built-in class. What I really need is to make a clone of an instance of an existing class, such `UIElement`, see my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13522001/silverlight-how-to-make-a-shallowcopy-of-a-uielement

Comment: What is that second line for??

Answer (score 38):

- you can´t use MemberwiseClone() directly, you must implement it via derived class (recomended)
- but, via reflection, you can cheat it :)
- you can use this litle extension for the classes that not implement ICloneable:

  ```
  /// <summary>
  /// Clones a object via shallow copy
  /// </summary>
  /// <typeparam name="T">Object Type to Clone</typeparam>
  /// <param name="obj">Object to Clone</param>
  /// <returns>New Object reference</returns>
  public static T CloneObject<T>(this T obj) where T : class
  {
      if (obj == null) return null;
      System.Reflection.MethodInfo inst = obj.GetType().GetMethod("MemberwiseClone",
          System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
      if (inst != null)
          return (T)inst.Invoke(obj, null);
      else
          return null;
  }
  ```

Comment: I cannot understand why MemberwiseClone isn't public... And the above "cheat" is very useful! Thumbs up!

Comment: In Silverlight, I got `System.MethodAccessException was unhandled by user code: Message=Attempt by method 'ExtensionStaticClass.MemberwiseCloneEx<System.__Canon>(System.__Canon)' to access method 'System.Object.MemberwiseClone()' failed`

Comment: In Silverlight can't use reflection to private members for security, limited by microsoft, you can use WCF serialization for clone

Comment: @Shaamaan: it's not public because it's up to the class-owner to determine how cloning should work; it's not necessarily safe for an arbitrary class to be cloned bit-for-bit. What would a bitwise clone of a `Thread` instance mean, for example?

Comment: this cheat works nicely, BUT beware of the performance impact due to usage of Reflection. I would'nt recommend using this function, if you have thousands (or even more) of clone operations to be done

Answer (score -1):

here is an extension method that allows the cloning of any object (use with the caveat that it not work in all cases)

```
public static class Extra_Objects_ExtensionMethods
{
    public static T clone<T>(this T objectToClone)
    {
        try
        {
            if (objectToClone.isNull())
                "[object<T>.clone] provided object was null (type = {0})".error(typeof(T));
            else
                return (T)objectToClone.invoke("MemberwiseClone");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            "[object<T>.clone]Faild to clone object {0} of type {1}".error(objectToClone.str(), typeof(T));
        }
        return default(T);
    }   
}
```