# Value types of variable size

Tags: c#, .net, math

I'm trying to code a small math library in C#. I wanted to create a generic vector structure where the user could define the element type (int, long, float, double, etc.) and dimensions.

My first attempt was something like this...

```
public struct Vector<T>
{
    public readonly int Dimensions;
    public readonly T[] Elements;

    // etc...
}
```

Unfortunately, Elements, being an array, is also a reference type. Thus, doing this,

```
Vector<int> a = ...;
Vector<int> b = a;
a[0] = 1;
b[0] = 2;
```

would result in both `a[0]` and `b[0]` equaling 2.

My second attempt was to define an interface `IVector<T>`, and then use Reflection.Emit to automatically generate the appropriate type at runtime. The resulting classes would look roughly like this:

```
public struct Int32Vector3 : IVector<T>
{
    public int Element0;
    public int Element1;
    public int Element2;

    public int Dimensions { get { return 3; } }

    // etc...
}
```

This seemed fine until I found out that interfaces seem to act like references to the underlying object. If I passed an `IVector` to a function, and changes to the elements in the function would be reflected in the original vector.

What I think is my problem here is that I need to be able to create classes that have a user specified number of fields. I can't use arrays, and I can't use inheritance.

Does anyone have a solution?

EDIT: This library is going to be used in performance critical situations, so reference types are *not* an option.

Comment: You could simply create a copy constructor and people will have to be aware of the fact that Vector<T> is a reference type, so a simple assignment may not be what they want.

Comment: What's the question? I simply don't get what you're trying to do. What are you trying to solve? You seem to misunderstand what assignment of references acheives. In your example, with a and b, after b=a, b and a refer to the same Vector instance.

Comment: b and a do not refer to the same instance - Vector<T> is a value type. However, both their `Elements` fields refer to the same instance, which is the problem with the first attempt.

Comment: Oops. Missed that it's a struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again, I had an epiphany in the shower.

I guess what I was kind of looking for was something like `var x = new Vector<int, 4>();`, which is impossible in C#. So, remembering [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/genericnumerics.aspx), my current solution is:

```
public struct Vector<TElement, TImpl> where TImpl : struct, IImplementation<TElement>
{
    private TImpl impl;

    public int Dimensions { get { return impl.Dimensions; } }

    public TElement this[int index]
    {
        get { return impl[index]; }
        set { impl[index] = value; }
    }
}
```

Thank you to everyone who responded.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `Clone` function in your classes, [MemberwiseClone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023210/help-with-c-memberwiseclone)

Something like the following:

```
class Vector : ICloneable {
    //...
    public Vector Clone() { return (Vector)this.MemberwiseClone(); }
    object ICloneable.Clone() { return Clone(); }
}
```

Comment: -1 This will not work either.  You need to perform a deep clone.  (This approach still doesn't copy the arrays, it just copies the references.  And `MemberwiseClone` is completely unnecessary for value types anyway.)

Comment: I vaguely remember reading something in Effective C# about ICloneable being evil. I'll look it up.

Comment: @YellPika: `ICloneable` isn't evil.

Comment: @YellPika, it's just not recommended. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699210/why-should-i-implement-icloneable-in-c

Comment: @Danny in this comment due to the notification system.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
public struct Vector<T>
{
    public readonly int Dimensions;
    public readonly T[] Elements;

    public Vector(Vector<T> source)
    {
        Dimensions = source.Dimensions;

        Elements = source.Elements != null ?
            (T[])source.Elements.Clone()
            : null;
    }

    public Vector<T> Clone()
    {
        return new Vector<T>(this);
    }

    // etc...
}
```

You will then have to make sure that you either use the copy constructor or the `Clone` method when you want to pass a copy of the structure.

Comment: That would mean I'd have to do someVar.Clone() every time I want to pass a vector to a function, which will be very often given the situation. Thats a *lot* of new arrays.

Comment: @Yell: Well, you can't have your cake and eat it too.  If you want the array copied, copy it.  If you don't, don't.